# How to attach domain to RHEL7 using the shell?

Tags: linux, hostname, domain

I would like to know what files must I edit in order to add a domain on a RHEL7 machine?

Example:

```
Hostname: Server1
Domain Name: qwer.tyu.iop
```

Result:

```
Server1.qwer.tyu.iop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do this via the `hostnamectl` command.

```
$ hostnamectl
   Static hostname: centos7
         Icon name: computer-vm
           Chassis: vm
        Machine ID: 1ec1e304541e429e8876ba9b8942a14a
           Boot ID: 1fccc9bc187646549c942457b95ed299
    Virtualization: kvm
  Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
       CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:centos:centos:7
            Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64
      Architecture: x86-64
```

To set your hostname:

```
$ hostnamectl set-hostname blah.blah.com
```

To confirm:

```
$ hostnamectl
   Static hostname: blah.blah.com
         Icon name: computer-vm
           Chassis: vm
        Machine ID: 1ec1e304541e429e8876ba9b8942a14a
           Boot ID: 1fccc9bc187646549c942457b95ed299
    Virtualization: kvm
  Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
       CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:centos:centos:7
            Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64
      Architecture: x86-64
```

**NOTE:** Doing it this way it'll persists between reboots etc.

#### References

- 3.3. [CONFIGURING HOST NAMES USING HOSTNAMECTL](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/networking_guide/sec_configuring_host_names_using_hostnamectl)

Comment: How do I add DNS servers?

Comment: @Angel - if you have follow up questions please mark this as the accepted answer if it solved your original question and ask a new one on the main site.